# Combining a topology with a different topology on a subspace

Tags: general-topology, notation, soft-question

Had the following idea: Let $Y\subseteq Z$ and let $T_Y, T_Z$ be topologies on the respective spaces. Define $T = \{A\in T_Z : A\cap Y \in T_Y\}$. It should be easy to verify that $T$ is a topology over $Z$.

As an example, take $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and consider cofinite and euclidean topologies. The resulting topology will consist of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ that either contain all but finitely many integers or none.

Is there a name for this method of constructing topologies / is this part of something more general?

Comment: What you have described is just the [final topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology) on $Z$ induced by two maps $(Y,T_Y)\hookrightarrow Z$ and $(Z,T_Z)\xrightarrow{\operatorname{id}_Z} Z$.

Comment: @user10354138 why not give it as an answer?